# How to hide particular field for specific role?

Tags: entities

I have Article page content type with field title,description,ad_article_top,video etc.
Also have one other role writer.writer can create article page content.

My issue is how to hide the ad_article_top field for writer role at the time he create content but if super admin create article page content the ad_article_top field not hidden

Give me some solution for solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
>
> Features
>
> - Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes.
>
>   - Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what access the user has.
>   - Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner is.
>   - Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature is needed.